# How do I overcome the problem of gas limit?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

**Here is my genesis.json file**

```
{  
   "config": {    
      "chainId": 1994,  
      "homesteadBlock": 0,  
      "eip155Block": 0,  
      "eip158Block": 0,  
      "byzantiumBlock": 0  
   },  
   "difficulty": "400",  
   "gasLimit": "2100000",  
   "alloc": {  
      "7b684d27167d208c66584ece7f09d8bc8f86ffff": {   
          "balance": "100000000000000000000000"   
      },  
      "ae13d41d66af28380c7af6d825ab557eb271ffff": {   
          "balance": "120000000000000000000000"   
      }  
   }  
}
```

**Here is the truffle-config.js**

```
networks  
{  
development: {  
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)  
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)  
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)  
      from: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",  
      gas: 200000,  
     },  
};
```

**Here is the 1_initial_migration.js**

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {  
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);  
};
```

I have kept the gas in the 1_initial_migration.js file lower than the gasLimit. But still, I find this error on using "truffle migrate":

Compiling your contracts...

===========================

> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

Migrations dry-run (simulation)

===============================

> Network name:    'development-fork'
>   Network id:      1
>   Block gas limit: 0x1388

1_initial_migration.js

======================

Deploying 'Migrations'

---

Error: Error: Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" exceeded the block limit (with a gas value you set).
   * Block limit:  0x50e7c
   * Gas sent:     20000
   * Try:
      + Sending less gas.
      + Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
        private network or test client (like ganache).

at Object.run
 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:84:1)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.0.18 (core: 5.0.18)
Node v8.10.0

Please give some solutions.

Thank you

Comment: `gas: 20000` is insufficient for any transaction whatsoever, as the minimum is 21000, and that's for a simple transfer of funds. For deployment you're gonna need a lot more than that.

Comment: I made it **gas: 200000**. but still, the same error shows up. - @goodvibration

Comment: `1_initial_migration.js` should contain code, not just some json object, what's going on here?????

Comment: i am really really sorry. i wrote wrong file name. kindly look into the question again, i have edited - @goodvibration

Comment: What is `from` doing in `truffle-config.js`???

Comment: if i don't have it, i have another error popping up which goes something like this    
         ** Error: Expected parameter 'from' not passed to function. at expected_keys**.. @goodvibration

Comment: "from" should be a valid ethereum address that has balance, use one of the accounts in your genesis file, change also your gas limit  in the genesis file “gasLimit”: “0x8000000”, and use Ganache instead of private BC, it is much easier

Comment: Thanks a million times. Using ganache helped and yes my account was invalid. Again thanks a lot. @MajdTL

Comment: welcome :) i will post that as answer and you can mark it as answer

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am not being able to find my genesis.json file. I have made the changes in truffle-config.js but it dosent work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/36357)

Comment: @nehaagarwal have you started ganache in another terminal? Make sure you remove the from: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
networks  
{  
development: {  
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)  
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)  
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)  
      from: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",  
      gas: 200000,  
     },  
};
```

**from** should be a valid ethereum address that has balance, use one of the accounts in your genesis file, change also your gas limit in the genesis file “gasLimit”: “0x8000000”.

And it is much easier and quicker to use Ganache instead of private BC

Comment: Yes. This issue resolved by switching from truffle develop to ganache-cli when running my tests.